# Class 'BaseController' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am using PHP MVC CI. BaseController and LoginController are both inside Controller Folder. When I run the Login Controller.  It says..

> Class 'BaseController' not found

**Login Controller**

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) die('No direct script access allowed');

    class loginController extends BaseController {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function login() {   
            $this->load->View("template/header");
            $this->load->View("login_view");
        }
    }
?>
```

**Base Controller**

```
<?php
    class BaseController extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            session_start();
            $this->load->library('session');
            parent::__construct();
        }
    }
?>
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Where is your base controller located?? same folder??

Comment: Inside Controller Folder !!!

Comment: Check of Casing in your class file name.

Comment: @Michal-sk웃 You mean Linux? Windows is case-insensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a parent controller than should be in

Path - `application/core/MY_Controller.php`

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
     }

}
```

If you also autoload sessions then you will not need to use `session_start`.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Filename: `Welcome.php` must be ***first letter uppercase*** in CI3

```
<?php

class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

}
```

CI 3 is case sensitive

Both user guides now here. CI2 & CI3 http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the file path , as follows:

application > controllers > Login.php

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) die('No direct script access allowed');

    class loginController extends BaseController {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function login() {   
            $this->load->View("template/header");
            $this->load->View("login_view");
        }
    }
?>
```

And, 
application > core > Base_controller.php

```
<?php
    class BaseController extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            session_start();
            $this->load->library('session');
            parent::__construct();
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter wont load it from the same folder.
You either put both classes in the same file, not desirable or put the base controller in **application/core**.
You will need to also set your prefix for you extended controller, for example `BASE_Controller`.
**application/config/config.php**

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'BASE_';
```

Codeigniter has good docs, and what you are after can be found [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/core_classes.html)